# Проблема кодировки. PHP, MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Всем привет! У меня произошла проблема с выводом русских символов из базы данных (InnoDB) с помощью **PHP**. Сравнение таблицы - **utf8_general_ci**. Но в браузере выводяться знаки вопроса в место русских букв. Я посмотрел кодировку с помощью **mb_detect_encoding**, вроде **ANSII**. Как можно решить такую проблему?

Comment: После коннекта к базе в обязательном порядке устанавливаете кодировку соединения (или даже во время коннекта, если это PDO).

Comment: stdClass Object ( [charset] => latin1 [collation] => latin1_swedish_ci [dir] => [min_length] => 1 [max_length] => 1 [number] => 8 [state] => 1 [comment] => ) - это mysqli_get_charset.

Comment: После коннекта делайте `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` или даже `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');` если база настроена на 4х байтовый UTF-8. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php